# Does current SonarQube support all the C# analysis functionality?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have been trying to setup a SonarQube instance which would include the test execution and coverage calculations. I have been using SonarQube 4.3.2 with C# Plugin 3.2.

What I wanted to use for tests / coverage was NUnit, Gallio & OpenCover

First problem I got was that irrelevant of the configuration there is no appearance of Gallio or mention of tests. Analysis itself runs fine but all other integration for C# stuff seems to be missing.

Then I tried with old plugins (C# Ecosystem, I tried 1.4 versions from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.dotnet.csharp) then gallio seems to work, but analysis brakes down, and when I try to use FxCop for instance it reports that rules could not be read ...

It is interesting to notice that there are no plugins for Gallio in 3.2 version (are they perhaps bundled inside this 3.2 C# plugin now?)

**To cut the story short, question is:**

Does the current SonarQube version (4.3.2) support all the functionality for C# (.NET) project analysis, including test execution and code coverage?

I have a feeling that only "basic" analysis is supported at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gallio support has been removed. From now on,You need to produce coverage files independently and import these files into sonar.

You can go through [this link](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugin) for further information